# Converting a date

Tags: selenium

I am using Selenium and using xpaths and I am trying to convert a date. I do have the DateTime library.

I need the date to be 1/15/23 but every time it logs it to console as 01/15/23. I am not sure why it logs it as 01 and not 1 on the month.

This is what I am using:

```
result_format=%m/%d/%y 12:00 AM    date_format=%m/%d/%Y

It wouldn't b a big deal but I am using that date to compare against another page and it fails because of the 01. 

Thanks for any help!
```

result_format=%m/%d/%y 12:00 AM    date_format=%m/%d/%Y

Expecting it to log like this: 1/15/23 12:00 AM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the datetime library and converted datetime to str and removed 0 from prefix.

```
import datetime

time1 = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17).strftime("%m/%d/%y 12:00 AM").removeprefix("0")
print(f"time1: {time1}")

time2 = datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 17).strftime("%m/%d/%y 12:00 AM").removeprefix("0")
print(f"time2: {time2}")
```

**Output**

```
time1: 5/17/20 12:00 AM
time2: 12/17/20 12:00 AM
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)